# will Hashbytes in T-SQL always return the same result?

Tags: t-sql, hashbytes

Will Hashbytes always return the same result for the same input
I mean 
if I call `HASHBYTES('SHA1',@value)` 100 time will the result always be the same?

Comment: Yes, that is sort of the point with secure hash algorithms. Same input => same output, but no way to go back to the input.

Answer (score 1):

It will return the same result for the same input value *and* data type.